# Haskell - wildcard use on right side of guard in patterns

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, guard

Lets say i have a piece of code like this:

```
test pattern
 | pattern == (_,NOT (WIRE _)) = 1     
 | pattern == (_,AND (WIRE _) (WIRE _)) = 2
 | otherwise = 0
```

Where i am trying to match it against one of several possibilities, some with one (WIRE ""), some with two. I have actual input as follows e.g.: ("p",NOT (WIRE "x")). I would like to have a pattern that could accept any letter as input (what i was hoping for with the _) and am failing dismally (illegal _). Is it possible to do this in haskell?

Comment: Strings are a list.  To pattern match a list, you use the list constructor, (:).  If you want to pattern-match a one-element list, try "x:[]" or "_:[]"

Comment: Are the _'s supposed to match each other (within the same guard)?

Comment: There are several confusing things about this question, but you should begin by not using guards at all but simply a sequence of equations like `test (_, NOT (WIRE _)) = 1`.

Comment: @LarsH no they real input provided would have them matched against p x. or if there were two wires p x x say.

@Reid Thanks! Why is it that it works like this and not within a guard?

Comment: To further Reid's idea, using this:

test2 (_,NOT (WIRE _))  = 1
test2 (_,AND (WIRE _)(WIRE _)) = 2

what is the best default (otherwise) case i.e. test2 _ = 0 equivalent. That doesn't work, and what i would like to say is any other input = 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, this makes a lot more sense after the edit.

`==` compares *values*, but `_` is a *pattern*.  Patterns appear in only the following syntactic contexts:

- on the left hand side of a (pattern) binding, i.e. "what's before `=`", at top level or in `where` blocks or in `let` expressions or commands (in `do` notation);
- to the left of `<-` in `do` notation or in a list comprehension;
- to the left of `->` in a `case` expression;
- as the formal arguments of functions, either in function bindings or lambda (`\`) expressions.

(I hope I haven't forgotten any!)  In your case, you can achieve what you want by simply writing

```
test (_, NOT (WIRE _)) = 1
test (_, AND (WIRE _) (WIRE _)) = 2
test _ = 0
```

---

You might ask what is the correct version of "`pattern == (_, NOT (WIRE _))`".  Well, you can write:

```
case pattern of
  (_, NOT (WIRE _)) -> True
  _ -> False
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it clears things up somewhat. Being haskell there is still a while till i feel completely comfortable with it though...

Comment: Great answer... educational as well as solutional. :-)

Comment: I think it's also worth pointing out the reverse: in pattern matching, all the identifiers are patterns and not values.  So `NOT` and `WIRE` need to be data constructors or (string or numeric) literals for that to work.  In this case it works, since they're upper case.  People learning Haskell often trip over this at some point.  For example, you can't test against constants by pattern matching - `f someNum = error "not that one!"` is not at all the same as `f x | x == someNum = error "not that one!"`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need guards for this?  Am I missing something?  Below is the legal Haskell code I think you're looking for.

```
test (_,NOT (WIRE _)) = 1     
test (_,AND (WIRE _) (WIRE _)) = 2
test _ = 0
```